# Angular mat dialog popout in new window

Tags: angular

I have an angular application showing a mat-dialog as a model. I want to open the dialog contents in a new popup window on clicking a button/link.

Using window.open and loading the dialog component doesn't work as it uses MatDialog

Comment: please share a code sample

Comment: There should be some route where you need this right?

Comment: can you please try to share some code, what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there should be some route if you open your application in new window/tab.

And in the constructor of the component you can make it (dialog open by default).

PS: IMO in such scenario you should Auxiliary routing (which is specially designed for Dialog related cases)

Read out in details [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#componentless-routes)